# Calculate Count of items summed up in a Group By Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Orders
======

id    total_price    created_on     

1     100            2021-01-22
2     200            2021-01-23
```

```
Items
=====
id     order_id

11     1
12     1
13     2
```

I want to create a query to get revenue by date. For this i'm going to sum up total price in order and grouping it up by date. Along with revenue, I also want to get total numbers of orders and items for that date. Here's a query that I wrote:

```
SELECT
    count(orders.id) as orders,
    sum(orders.total_price) as billing,
    DATE(CREATED_ON) as created_on
    FROM
        orders
    WHERE orders.deleted_on IS NULL
    group by Date(orders.created_on);
```

Now I found 2 problems:

1. The count of orders is coming incorrect. Not sure what. i'm doing wrong here.
2. How can I calculate the count of items also in same query ?

I'm learning sql and this seems a big difficult to get my head around. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's odd to have a column called order-I'd in a table called items. This would normally be an order_details table or order_items, or similar. Anyway, it sounds like you want to count(DISTINCT o.id)

Comment: @Strawberry This is actually a foreign key pointing to orders table ID. As you can see each order can have multiple items

Comment: So what does *coming incorrect* actually mean? Your sample data is insufficient to demonstrate your issue and doesn't even correlate with the columns used in your example query.

Answer (score 0):

As Items.order_id is foreign key to Order.id as a result we need to join both tables first.

```html
SELECT count(order_id) AS orders,sum(total_price) AS billing,Orders.created_on as created_on FROM Orders,(select order_id from Items) as new WHERE Orders.id=new.order_id GROUP BY created_on;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because when you combine the items you might multiple the revenue.  One method is to aggregate the items before joining to orders:

```
SELECT DATE(o.Created_On) as created_on_date,
       COUNT(*) as num_orders,
       SUM(i.num_items) as num_items,
       SUM(o.total_price) as billing
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT i.order_id, COUNT(*) as num_items
      FROM items i
      GROUP BY i.order_id
     ) i
    ON i.order_id = o.id
WHERE o.deleted_on IS NULL
GROUP BY DATE(o.created_on);
```

Note:  This uses a `LEFT JOIN` because you have not specified that all orders have items.  If all do then an `INNER JOIN` would suffice.